# WhisperAI not importing correctly?

Tags: openai-whisper

I'm in Jupyter Notebook and having a problem where my whisper isn't working properly. My code matches the README from the official documentation, but it's not being recognized. I've relaunched Jupyter already.

I think I have the wrong whisper imported. I know that there's something else in python called whisper. How do I check and fix this?

python code:

`model = whisper.load_model("tiny", device = 'cuda')`

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 model = whisper.load_model("tiny", device = 'cuda')

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'load_model'
```

I've already relaunched Jupyter.

I was expecting the model to be loaded properly.

Edit: I've launched a new Notebook, imported whisper, and found with dir(whisper) that they each have different attributes, so I'm sure that the problem is that I have the wrong whisper imported.

Comment: You seem to be tracking down the issue yourself. Because you leave out all the details of the original installation(s), how you are actually importing things, and what `dir()` actually says, it is very hard for anyone to help you. This is all stuff you would have worked out before posting and included in the post. Another way to look at it is that your issue is something specific to your computer system now. We don't have access, and so it is hard for us to advise on unless you thoroughly follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

I defined a function with the same name: whisper()

Answer (score -1):

If you are facing same issue in Colab: Restart the session. That worked for me.